# How to define a default list of attributes for instances of a class?

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I have a few objects in my program that have about 10-15 attributes each. These attributes are set at various places in the code in various stages in the program. As it is absolutely fine to set them on the objects without having them defined in the class in Python, there's no good authoritative list in my program of which attributes are used.

I'd like something like the following:

```
class MyObject(object):
    attr1
    attr2
```

I've looked at the `property()` built-in, but it's at least 6 lines of code per property. Is there an easy way to define a list of default attributes without initializing them in Python?

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention, most of the values don't have sensible defaults and would effectively be equal to `None` before used.

Comment: Do you want the ones with no default added with a value of `None`? Not sure what to make of the info in your update...

Comment: I don't really know what's the most pythonic way, I just know that I can't give all attributes a value upon object creation.

Comment: Commonly they're all defined in the `__init__()` method even if it's just to set them to `0`, `None`, or `''` as a way to document them all. On the other hand, it perfectly permissible to not define one unless the object is in a certain state, but it may be harder for others to understand.

Comment: And also implicit, from the code that uses the objects, not the class definition. Setting them to `None` works just fine for my purposes.

Comment: The second thing in [PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is "Explicit is better than implicit." Just sayin'... ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Hugh Bothwell is on the right track, but it can be done more concisely:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _defaults = "attr1", "attr2", "attr3"
    _default_value = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(dict.fromkeys(self._defaults, self._default_value))
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


my_object = MyClass(attr3='overridden', attr4='added')

print(vars(my_object))
```

Output:

```
{'attr4': 'added', 'attr2': None, 'attr3': 'overridden', 'attr1': None}
```

I made `_defaults` and `_default_value` class attributes (which could be changed at runtime). (Providing a **mutable default value** would likely require additional code to prevent it from being shared by every instance created, however.)

This would be easy to extend to allow defining different (immutable) default values for each default attribute:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _defaults = {
        "attr1": None,
        "attr2": 0,
        "attr3": ""
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(self._defaults)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


my_object = MyClass(attr3='overridden', attr4='added')

print(vars(my_object))
```

Output:

```
{'attr4': 'added', 'attr2': 0, 'attr3': 'overridden', 'attr1': None}
```

Comment: Excellent!  I forgot about self.__dict__ - this is definitely a more succinct way of doing it.

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, attr1 = default1, attr2 = default2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
```

You can instantiate a `MyObject` with or without specifying the attributes

```
myObject1 = MyObject() # gets default values 
myObject2 = MyObject(foo, bar) # overrides defaults
```

You could also use keyword arguments (`kwargs`) if you have a variable number of attributes, see [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) for examples.

Comment: See my update above, I don't have default values for all attributes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have many properties to be passed, it may be more readable this way:

```
class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            "attr1": None,
            "attr2": 0,
            "attr3": ""
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        for attr,value in defaults.iteritems():
            self.__setattr__(attr, value)
```

**Edit:** looking at @martineau and @kosii's suggestions, here is another possibility:

```
class MyClass(object):
    defaults = {
        "attr1": None,
        "attr2": 0,
        "attr3": ""
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            # return a default value
            return MyClass.defaults[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError("don't recognize .{}".format(key))
```

... in this case, recognized object attributes return default values if they have not actually been set yet.

Comment: Your update is an interesting idea -- sort of like having "virtual attributes". However I'd be a little leery of doing this because a potential problem might be that if a default attribute had a mutable value that was changed via one instance (like appending to a list), then that change would show up in all other existing instances as well as any new ones subsequently created. On the other hand, maybe that's a "feature", although it may run counter to the principle of least surprise...

Answer (score 1):

What about a little play with `__getattr__`?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, special_attrs=[]):
        self.__dict__['_special_attrs_dict'] = dict.fromkeys(special_attrs)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self._special_attrs_dict:
            return self._special_attrs_dict[key]
        raise AttributeError('')

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self._special_attrs_dict:
            self._special_attrs_dict[key] = value
        else:
            super(A, self).__setattr__(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can create class attributes with default values. This can be especially useful if a class can have many attributes but many of them are often left unset, or if the instances are serialized you can ensure you only serialize/de-serialize the non-default attributes and just ignore the ones with the default values.

e.g.

```
class MyObject(object):
    attr1 = 42
    attr2 = ()

instance = MyObject()
for x in instance.attr2:
    print(x)
```

Now any `MyObject` instance has `attr1` and `attr2` attributes whether or not they are explicitly set. Note that if you want a default value to be a sequence you should be sure to use a tuple so that it cannot be mutated accidentally.